# Fill up empty space if <td> is empty in <tr>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table and it has two rows columns.
If one of them is empty,  should move up to upper row.

Example: 
Initially-

`|td1 | td2|
 |td3 |    |
 |td5 | td6|`

What I need-

`|td1 | td2|
 |td3 | td5|
 |td6 |    |`

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="row pl-3 bg-white" id="interests">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-borderless table-condensed table-responsive-md">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</td>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_ITspends.svg"></img>
            </img>
          </th>
          <td>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_investors.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td>
          <!-- <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_Hiring.svg"></img></th>
                                    <td>What if this doesn't exist. Can I move td below here?</td> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_Interest Signals.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum”.</td>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_WebsiteTechStack.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_Events.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td>
          <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="assets/ic_CompanyTechStack.svg"></img>
          </th>
          <td>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something here? I had two tables before in each col-md-6. Now I have made only one table so rows are rearranged, but they don't.

Comment: Use JS to copy-paste content or use non-table approach.

Comment: Tables don't magically rearrange themselves. You have to construct the table in the correct format when you generate it. Or, since this does not look like tabular data, don't use a table!

Comment: Little or no experience with this but how do I not use tables here? I tried remaking this with <div>'s but was not able to align images as table does.

Comment: you cannot move td from 1 tr to another inn css.. You will have to do it in jquery or javascript.. You have to use tables only ?

Comment: @XenioGracias No, I don't specifically need tables

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to use CSS / Bootstrap to make it happen? I'm not sure if it is do-able with CSS alone and if it is, it probably requires too much effort to no system gain. It is easy to do with JavaScript. Do you have any code attempt apart from the HTML provided?

Comment: @Mayur Bhangale Try using div's.

Comment: @XenioGracias I tried remaking this with <div>'s but was not able to align images as table does.

Comment: @José Not really

Comment: @Mayur Bhangale i have added 1 answer. please check

Comment: @XenioGracias Are you sure you've posted? Can't find below

Comment: Sound like a CSS Grid will fit your need better than a table. CSS Grid does that thing you want by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. The "Cards" (image with text) are not wrapping when 1 of them is empty
2. If not using `<table>`, the images are not shown as it is in a table.

Here are 2 appraoches:

### A. `col-md-6` for Cards, and use `<table>` inside

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tep0rwhc/1/)

```
<div class="row pl-3 bg-white" id="interests">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><img id="icons" src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></th>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</td>   
...
```

The image will be vertically aligned to center and the text will be as close to the image as possible (aligned to the left).

We may use other elements and use Flex or Grid etc. instead of `<table>`.

### B. `col-md-2` for Images and `col-md-4` for Text, and fix image position

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdu9mvbf/)

HTML

```
<div class="row pl-3 bg-white" id="interests">
  <div class="col-md-2" data-scope="row"><img id="icons" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</div>
...
```

CSS

```
[data-scope="row"] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

[data-scope="row"] > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This approach gives us less wrapping elements (`<div>` and `<table>`) and we can tweak the position of image as we want.  The distance between the image and text is fixed.

P.S.

1. The `data-scope` attribute is not necessary.  We can use other CSS selector, like adding one more CSS class.
2. It is not recommended to use the same ID (`icons`) more than once.  The code provided in the Fiddles are for illustration for layout.

Comment: `scope` attribute is for `th` elements, not `div`, and will here be non valid syntax. Let me know when you edit that.

Comment: Edited. Thanks @LGSon! Please check if that's better.

Comment: That looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created your table in div. hope this helps you. thanks

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row pl-4 bg-white" id="interests">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3"id="icons" src="assets/ic_Funding.svg">
  <div class="media-body">
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real good way to do what you're looking for with HTML tables directly. tr's are table rows explicitly. So anything in 2 different tr's will be in two different rows.
What I recommend is actually making a table with 1 row and 2 cells. And in each cell, use div's (might need to change the display css to make it work perfectly) for the column items.

Something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>td1</div>
      <div>td3</div>
      <div>td6</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>td1</div>
      <div>td3</div>
      <div>td6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

By default, div's display as a new line but you might need to change the div's display from the default block to something else depending on what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `flex` instead of `table` elements.

Here is a perfectly fine example on how you want to use it in your case:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: blue;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <div class="element">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The essential part of a code sample should be within the answer, not as an external link alone.